# Extract Instagram follower in a Google spreadsheet via function

Tags: xml-parsing, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet in which automatically the amount of instagram follower will be extracted and added for every day. Unfortunately, Instagram changed their Code and my function doesn't work anymore. Can you Help?

My Sheet is separated in a time stamp and the amount of followers for each day.

```
=mid(
  regexextract(
    query(
      IMPORTXML(C1,"//*[@class]"),
      "select Col3"
    ),
    "followed_by.{4}[a-z]{5}?..[0-9]{1,}"),
   23,
   20
 )
```

Comment: can you share a sample profile url to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually achieve it by using importdata and regexreplace:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(CONCATENATE(IMPORTDATA(B1)),"(^.*followed_by: {""count"": )(\d+)(}.*)","$2")
```

[image]